# why my ajax not running on form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

My ajax not running on form ...when I submit form it perform nothing..please help.

```
 $( '#my-form' )
  .submit( function( e ) {
    $.ajax( {
      url: 'u_mainslides.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData( this ),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    } );
    e.preventDefault();
  } ); 
</script>    

<form action=""   method="post" id="my-form" >    
     <label for="title">Title:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="mainslides/08">  
     <label >Upload:</label>
     <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary"   name="file">
      <input type="submit"  value="Done" name="Submit" id="submit"/>   
    </form>
```

Comment: Open developers console and check errors. And don't forget `document.ready`

Comment: i have $( document ).ready(function() { and check console...no error found facing same problem.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype and append form text data. 
Your code shoul look like this:

```
$( '#my-form' )
.submit( function( e ) {

var fd=new FormData(document.getElementById("my-form"));
fd.append("title",$(".form-control").val());

$.ajax( {
  url: 'u_mainslides.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success:function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
} );
e.preventDefault();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `done()` and `fail()` functions to your `$.ajax()`

```
$('#submit').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
   var data = new FormData($('#my-form')[0]);
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'u_mainslides.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (data) {
          // returned data
          console.log(data);
       }).fail(function (){
         //handle fail
       });
 }
```